# How to connect two shapes in Raphael by dragging the mouse?

Tags: javascript, raphael

Im trying to connect two shapes using the path by dragging the mouse from one shape to the other.Is this possible in Rapahael?If some one has already done this a lttle help will be much appreciated.

Im looking to do something like below.I want to be able to drag my mouse from the grey shape to other green shape and connect them using a path

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Did you find a good solution yet? I'm trying to make a similar app.

Answer (score 1):

i'd approach it like so:

1. create a [`set`](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Set) to hold the shapes once they're joined.
2. assign a [`drag()` handler](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.drag) to the desired element, to push it to the set upon dragging (with certain constrains, obviously - if shapes are intersecting or other conditions).
3. treat the set (now containing several shapes) as the new shape, as `Raphael`'s `set` API allows precisely this by providing an opaque interface to the contained shapes inside the `set` object.

i hope this helps, for any questions or clarifications on this, please comment. i'll try and manifest another approach for a solution, and see if i'd come up with anything.